# MySQL `where...in` statement - does it remove duplicates?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm curious about if MySQL's `where ... in (...)` statement removes duplicates as an optimization.

For example, if I use a subquery, is it important that I use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates?

An example query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM bar where user_id = 4
);
```

The subquery has the potential to return duplicate `bar.id`'s.

Does MySQL query optimization make this query better?

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM bar where user_id = 4
);
```

From my tests on a database with about 2.5mm rows in the `bar` table (with indexes where appropriate for such a query), the result time is roughly the same (on a large RDS instance with plenty of overhead for now).

> I should note that I'm hoping for an explanation more than "the subquery returns less results when using `DISTINCT`, so of course it's better", as that ignores MySQL's query optimizer.
>
> For example, perhaps `DISTINCT` uses more resources and is therefore slower overall, especially if a `where...in(...)` statement easily optimizes duplicates. These are the details I'm unsure about.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `user_id` is not a `PRIMARY KEY`, then MySQL will need to de-duplicate the subquery to apply the correct semantics. The `DISTINCT` keyword should not be required here since it doesn't change the semantics.

MySQL actually has more than one strategy for how to remove duplicates: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-optimization.html

To see the strategy used, you need to paste the output from `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` (it does not appear in the regular tabular EXPLAIN). You will see something like:

```
     "transformation": {
                   "select#": 2,
                   "from": "IN (SELECT)",
                   "to": "semijoin",
                   "chosen": true
                 }
```